# Missing variable when triggering bicep based deployment with devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep

I'm trying to use Azure devops pipelines to deploy azure resources using a bicep file.
This process works if I use powershell to deploy but I'm hitting a problem with devops.

In the bicep file I have the following

```
param environmentType string
var stgSubID = 'xxxx'
var prodSubID = 'xxxx'


var subscriptionID = (environmentType == 'prod') ? prodSubID : stgSubID
```

By entering prod or stg at deployment time I can set certain other values further down the file.

In devops I created the following pipeline but it failed because the `subscriptionID` wasn't present. I'd like to keep the conditional variable rather than creating duplicate pipelines as this will only complicate pipelines that run after this..

After some searching I came across this approach but it also fails.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: environment
    value: $(environment)
  - name: environmentType
    ${{ if eq( variables['environment'], 'stg') }}:
      value: $(stgSubID)
    ${{ if eq( variables['environment'], 'prod' ) }}:
      value: $(prodSubID)


jobs:
- job:
  steps:

  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      connectedServiceName: $(ServiceConnectionName)
      location: $(location)
      deploymentName: $(deploymentName)
      resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroupName)
      csmFile: templates/newRegion.bicep
      csmParametersFile: deployments/newRegion/$(shortlocation)-$(environmentType).parameters.json
      overrideParameters: >
        -connectivitySubID $(connectivitySubID)
        -stgSubID $(stgSubID)
        -prodSubID $(prodSubID)
        -managementSubID $(managementSubID)
        -subscriptionID ${{variables.environmentType}}
```

**TL:DR** How do a set variable X to the value of another variable in Azure devops based on the input provided at run time and pass that to a bicep file for deployment.

Comment: I am confused as to why you are passing the subscription ID. Bicep can get the context on the subscription and/or management group [by setting the `targetScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-to-management-group?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: The bicep file creates resource groups in multiple different subscriptions and then creates resources in those resource groups.

Comment: Are they all in the same Management Group?

Comment: No, they are all under the same root but several levels down and separate at that level

Comment: Are you not able to use the native arguments in the [ARMDeployment@3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) task?  If your bicep file is configured to deploy only some resources to one subscription and some to another would recommend separate files and/or leverage a registry

Comment: I have thought about separating the file, currently the outputs are used extensively within the file. It would mean a huge rewrite to using existing resources references over and over. At the moment, I input location and either stg or prod and that is it, the whole regions resources are provisioned. I might just keep this to powershell as it has a finite number of runs, unlike my other pipelines which run on various tiggers x times a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think you need to refactor your approach as other guys stated I will answer your question: *TL:DR How do a set variable X to the value of another variable in Azure DevOps based on the input provided at run time and pass that to a bicep file for deployment.*

According to your example, you have 3 pipeline variables:

- $(environment)
- $(stgSubID)
- $(prodSubID)

When you set environment = stg during pipeline execution then environmentType variable which you will be passing to deployTask should be set to $(stgSubID) else $(prodSubID).

You can resolve this problem by introducing an additional job that will determine the variable and output it to another job using the [output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables)

```
jobs:
- job: DetermineEnvironmentTypeJob
  steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $environmentType = "$(prodSubID)"
        if("$(environment)" -eq "stg") {
          $environmentType = "$(stgSubID)"
        }
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=environmentTypeOutput;isoutput=true]$environmentType"
      name: SetEnvironmentType

- job: TemplateDeploymentJob
  dependsOn: DetermineEnvironmentTypeJob
  variables:
    environmentType: $[ dependencies.DetermineEnvironmentTypeJob.outputs['SetEnvironmentType.environmentTypeOutput'] ]  
  steps:
    - pwsh: |
        Write-Host "Environment type $(environmentType)"
      displayName: DeployStep
```

Verification:
Pipeline variables value:
$(stgSubID) = 1
$(stgProdID) = 2

Test 1:
Execute pipeline with environment set to 'stg'.
Result: environmentType = 1

Test 2
Execute pipeline with environment set to 'prod'.
Result: environmentType = 2

If you need to use this approach I should at least recommend using the [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-in-pipelines) with a restricted list of values stg, prod instead of environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have what appears to be a typo in your YAML. You set `environment` to be equal to the value of `environment`, which is going to resolve to empty. If it's a variable that's being entered at deployment time, please refer to the documentation on variables and compilation-time expressions (`${{}}`). Runtime variables exist *after* compilation time, so your variable cannot resolve; you cannot use runtime variable values in compilation-time expressions.

The correct way to address this is to use multiple stages. Have a stage for STG and a stage for PROD. Then you can choose the stage to deploy at deployment time via the built-in stage selection UI. You can extract the job to a template and expose parameters where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.... I think I had come to the same conclusion but wasn't sure why it didn't exist.

Comment: Having looked at this further I understand more now where and where the variables exist and explains why through various attempts to solve this I always came back to the variable being blank if I based it on the pipeline variable.